# Weired result of Ltspice Zin measurement, Phase shift of -104°

Tags: ltspice, impedance-matching, input-impedance

I am trying to measure the input impedance of this amplifier to design a matching network for it. But the input impedance I get has a phase of -104° at the frequency of interest. I thought that Phase could only go from -90° to 90° how is -104° possible and where do I plot it on a smiths chart? Magnitude 31 Ohms. Thanks for helping out.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any phase angle is possible between two sinusoidal signals. For example, 180° means that they're perfectly out of phase - or in other words, inverted with respect to each other.

-104° means that power is flowing in the opposite direction than what you expected.

In general, any impedance vector pointing into the right half plane of the coordinate system means that power is flowing into the device in question, while a vector pointing into the left half plane (such as yours) indicates that power is flowing out of it.

You might've just accidentally flipped the sign of the current or voltage that you're using to calculate the impedance. Alternatively, the circuit might exhibit resonant peaking, causing it to deliver power to the signal source rather than consuming power from it.

Also note that the input impedance of this amplifier will vary drastically with the gain of the transistor. It's anything but well-defined. The 2N3904 is also extremely ill-suited to operation at such high frequencies. The DC operating point of your circuit also looks to be questionable; the transistor is likely not amplifying at all given its low collector-emitter voltage.

Comment: ah okay I see thanks, just a quick question, what small signal npn transistor would you recommend for this frequency?

Comment: Something with a transition frequency that is an order of magnitude greater than your signal frequency - a BFS17NTA might work (ft=3.2GHz). That way you will still have some gain left at your desired ~150MHz. There are hundreds of other transistors with even higher ft in stock at Digi-Key in the radio frequency bipolar transistor category.